# Sending Hashchange events to Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've been trying to get around GA's dislike for url hash changes by pushing an event with the view name every time the hash url changes. The idea being that it should show up as a new page every time the event fires off. Unfortunately the analytics seems to only be showing the initial user/ data and then falling off into oblivion, instead of showing the expected user#profile or user#help. My code is as follows:

```
  ga('create', '<?= $googleCode ?>',{
    'userId': '<?= $userId ?>'
  });
  ga('send', 'pageview');

  function sendAnalytics() {
      var pageName = location.hash.replace('#', '');
      ga('send', 'screenview', {
        'page': location.pathname + location.search + location.hash,
        'screenName': pageName
      });
  }
  window.onhashchange = sendAnalytics;
```

I know I'm probably misusing the GA tracking, but there has to be a way to track single page application views right?

Comment: I assume you already know all of this and that it didn't help? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications

Comment: @Shilly Yes unfortunately, the view we want to track on this SPA are all hash urls.